# Scheduler not working in openerp

Tags: odoo

I want create a scenario ,when stock will become below a minimum level an automatic purchase order need to be placed.For that I have Created a minimum stock rule(reordering rule).So when product qty become less than minimum quantity a purchase order will be placed using the option
'warehouse->scheduler->run scheduler' It is working fine. But I need to place the purchase order   automatically in monthly or weekly base, without using the option 'warehouse->scheduler->run scheduler'.So for that I have tried to use the scheduling option I have write the code like this.

```
<record forcecreate="True" id="ir_cron_purchase_fine_action" model="ir.cron">
  <field name="name">Run Purchase Fine Scheduler</field>
  <field eval="True" name="active" />
  <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root" />
  <field name="interval_number">1</field>
  <field name="interval_type">days</field>
  <field name="numbercall">1</field>
  <field eval="'purchase.order'" name="model" />
  <field eval="'run_scheduler'" name="function" />
  <field eval="'(False,)'" name="args" />
</record>
```

But scheduling is not working , I have also tried to create schedule from the option 'administartion->schedule->scheduled action' . But Still the scheduling is not working and no purchase order is placed in it. I am doing this on my local machine,not on server  is that the issue.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set the `numbercall=-1`

```
<field name="numbercall">-1</field>
```

If you give 1, then your scheduler will run only once. If you given -1 then it runs infinitely.